# passing login data from ajax to php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my script in the html page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').on('submit',function(e){
            var loginid=$('#loginid').val();
            var password=$('#password').val();
            alert("loginid="+loginid);
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST", 
                 url: "../controller/login_check.php",
                 data: {loginid:loginid,password:password},
                 success: function(html) {
                     //alert(html);
                     $('#status').html(html);
                 }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to get the values from the html input boxes and then passing those values to the ajax code which passes it to the php script, which then validates the login id and password and echoes a message

The php script:

```
<?php
    require_once('dbconfig.php');
    //if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {
        $loginid = $_POST['loginid'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if ($operations->login($loginid, $password)) {
            header("Location:../view/admin_home.php");
        } else {
            echo "wrong details";
        }
    //}
    $conn = null;
?>
```

html div where message should be printed:

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

When I run the code in the browser no errors are shown, but the code does not work and neither the message is displayed nor is the validation done.

Comment: If you place `exit("Test")` at the top of the PHP page, does that output to the `div`?

Comment: It's your js that's breaking somewhere I would see if it's the file locations or something to do with that. Is it getting to the alert("loginId=" + loginId)

Comment: You must redirect with javascript, you are not actually going to the php page, you are just retrieving whatever is echoed.

Comment: Have you included the latest version of jQuery? As the code is not complete. I have to ask.

Comment: just used preventDefault function and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My contribution:

In ajax requests I suggest you to end the php script, you can use a simple die(); for this. After this, you must to print the response, you can use numeric or string pattern to expose this like: 'success' or 'fail', also: 1 or 0.

Here is the same example with a new solution:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').on('submit',function(e){
            var loginid = $('#loginid').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            e.preventDefault(); //for avoiding conflict with default form function
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST", 
                 url: "../controller/login_check.php",
                 data: {loginid: loginid, password: password},
                 success: function(response) {
                     if (response == 'success') {

                         // if a successful response, redirect your client
                         window.location.href = '../view/admin_home.php';
                     } else {

                         // if login fails, put a message on screen
                         $('#status').html('Wrong credentials, try again.');
                     }
                 }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget to filter data in php, never trust in your user!

```
require_once('dbconfig.php');

// pre setting a response status as fail, this avoid you to use an
// else statement
$result = 'fail';

if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {

    // Apply filter and sanitize data, if the loginid is an e-mail 
    // use the FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL else a simple string filter is ok.
    $loginid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'loginid', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if($operations->login($loginid,$password)){

        // If everything is ok, you just override the response message
        $result = 'success';
    }
}

// Ath the end you simply close the connection, print the response and
// stops the PHP script
$conn = null;
print(result);
die();
```

Comment: actually no need for input filter as its a login form the data should be exact

Comment: Are you sure? What will happen if som user put some like this:

"email@domain.com 105 or 1=1"

Good luck!

Here is the reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp. 

Of course, that it is just an example are everything ok, but in production never trust in user.

Comment: i have used error handling to tackle the problem of sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url:  "../controller/login_check.php",
            data: form.serialize()
        }).done(function (html) {
            $('#status').html(html);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you were too fast ;)

Comment: My computer shows 2 minutes ago. You can use 4-spaces or using ```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by preventing it from performing the default function

i used e.preventDefault() it worked but i have a new problem now 
the page to which the php script tries to redirect appears on the same login page how should i solve this now??
[here is a screen shot of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWqNi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must redirect with javascript, you are not actually going to the php page, you are just retrieving whatever is printed.

```
window.open(page,'_self')
```

rather than

```
header(...)
```